# Jest.mock outside variable reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

There is need to mock 1 react component, just simple dummy mock, for snapshot testing.

When I try to call `React.Component` **inside** the mock function, i got an error:

> The second argument of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any
>   outside variables.

But if i call `require('react').Component`, that works!
Is there any human-ish way to do it correctly?

My code:

```
//This one fails
import React from ('react');
...
    jest.mock('...', () => { return class ... extends React.Component {
            render(){
                return <span/>
            }

    }});

//This one works
import React from ('react');
...
jest.mock('...', () => { return class ... extends require('react').Component {
            render(){
                return <span/>
            }

    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Based on GitHub thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567)

> This used to be a bug that we fixed. In a mock you can only require
>   things locally and you aren't allowed to access external variables.

you can change your code this way to make it work

```
jest.mock('...', () => {
  const React = require ('react')
  return class ... extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <span />
    }    
  }
})
```

Comment: But if you want to change a variable? Think that you want to mock a function that has one object and for testing purposes in one test it has to be true and other false. How can I do it that now?